# arm-eabi-gcc :command not found when trying to set up LiME

Tags: android, compilation

I am out of idea's. I feel like I've done everything correctly. I'm trying to capture a memory image from android using LiME. If I do the following...

```
   $ cd $my_android_ndk_path/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/
   $ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- modules_prepare
```

it returns

```
    make: *** No rule to make target `modules_prepare'.  Stop.
```

If i type the same command from my Kernel Source (where my .config is located)
        $ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=path/to/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-eabi- modules_prepare

it returns

```
    make: /path/to/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: Command not found
    CHK     include/linux/version.h
    make[1]: `include/asm-arm/mach-types.h' is up to date.
    CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
    SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-arm
    CC      kernel/bounds.s
```

I am sure my directories are right. Does anyone have any idea what i could be doing wrong.  I'm not using any particular tool for the ndk. I just unzipped the ndk and sdk seperatly and installaled JDK. Everything should work but it doesn't.

Comment: and by the way... I'm obviously not actually typing in "/path/to/android_ndk/" ... that's just to help your eyes

Comment: Would you consider changing the question title?  It doesn't seem to be particularly descriptive of the problem.

Comment: yes.... as soon as i can figure out where to do that

Comment: At the bottom of your question, to the left of your user ID box, do you have an "edit" link?

Answer (score 1):

did you check the compatibility between your arm-eabi-gcc (command: file /arm-eabi-gcc) compiler and your machine (32 or 64-bits)?
If your arm-eabi-gcc is 32-bits machine compatible, to prevent errors like "make: arm-eabi-gcc: Command not found" in a 64-bits machine, you must install the package "ia32-libs" (command: sudo apt-get install ia32-libs).

Answer (score 0):

`modules_prepare` is a kernel preparation routine.  Its purpose is to make sure that enough of the header files exist that you could subsequently build a kernel module against that kernel source tree.  You see, the kernel has some auto-generated files, and without running at least `modules_prepare`, a kernel module compilation will not be possible.

To this end, when you run modules_prepare from the kernel tree, that's a correct action.  Running it from the cross compiler makes no sense because it doesn't understand what you're trying to do.

I'll recommend you make your life easier by adding the cross compiler to the PATH as so:

```
PATH=$PATH:$my_android_ndk_path/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/
cd <kernel directory>
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- modules_prepare
```

So this said...  modules_prepare is just the first step in preparing to build a module.  If you're trying to build a kernel module <strike>(LiME? I don't know what that is)</strike> then you'll need to [follow the steps for building a kernel module](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt).

Edit:

Now that I know what kernel module you're building (lime-forensics) I can see its [SVN sources](http://code.google.com/p/lime-forensics/source/browse/trunk/src/Makefile).  The Makefile expects that you're building for your local computer, and not cross-compiling.

Change the following:

```
default:
        $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(KVER)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

to

```
default:
        $(MAKE) -C <your Android kernel> ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- M=$(PWD) modules
```

That will likely get you further.

Comment: I took your advice and added it to my path. You were right. That was much easier. I am still however stuck with my problem.  I'm following the pdf installation step by step and i still get the 'make: arm-eabi-gcc: Command not found" error. The pdf is here.  The installation page is one 1 page long if anyone has time to look. http://code.google.com/p/lime-forensics/downloads/detail?name=LiME_Documentation_1.1.pdf&can=2&q=

Comment: I updated the answer with some more information, now that the kernel module is identified.

Comment: Thanks. This actually really will help me when it comes time to compile LiME, but compiling Lime isn't where my error occurs. It's hard to explain without reading the pdf tutorial. I will continue to try and figure it out. Thanks for your help.